# What does e.target.style.height = '5px' do?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a code something like (I got this code from someone else, I asked them to explain but couldn't):

```html
<textarea 
  onInput={event => {
    event.target.style.height = '5px'
    event.target.style.height = event.target.scrollHeight + 'px'
  }}
/>
```

This code stretches the textarea when the there is new line/line wrap in that textarea. If I comment first line text area's height actually increase, but works as expected if first line is not commented. I checked the height using inspect element but the height doesn't change. I also console logged the height using `console.log(event.target.offsetHeight)` but, the value always remains the same.

So, what do this two lines do?

Answer (score 3):

They are intended to make the textarea dynamically change the height to fit the content. The purpose of setting the height to '5px' first and then to event.target.scrollHeight + 'px' is to force the textarea to recalculate its height based on the updated content.

Comment: @AbidHasan it could be that you have some *other* control over the textbox, eg css that's overriding the js.   Your code works as expected and described here.  See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/1v82oshu/  run and put a few lines of text in the textarea.